# Cannot Create this procedure in MySQL

Tags: mysql

im trying to create a procedure im MySQL Management Studio and I cant find the problem.
The procedure is destined to increment the price of Flights from Thailand by 5%.

This is the table of Flights:

```
create table Flights
(
flightnumber varchar(30) primary key,
departure varchar(30),
destination varchar(30),
flightdate date ,
planemodel varchar(30),
price int,
);
```

and this is the query im trying the execute:

```
alter proc setprice
as begin
declare @precent int 
declare @numofrow int
declare @i int
declare @newprice int
declare @n int
select @i=0 
select @precent=5
select @i=0
select @numofrow= (select count(Flights.flightnumber) from Flights )
select @n= 1.0+@precent/100
while ( @i<@numofrow)
begin
select @newprice=(select Flights.price@n from Flights where flights.flightnumber=@i)
update Flights set price=@newprice where destination='Bangkok - Survernabumi'
select @i=@i+1
end
end
```

Comment: What problem are actually you trying to solve?

Comment: this procedure i posted is built on an example from my lecturer, its suppouse to increase the price of flight to 'Bangkok' by 5%.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're updating the price for a different flight than the one you selected. You're also never multiplying the price by `@n`, and statements like

```
select @i = 0
```

should be

```
SET @i = 0
```

And you need `;` between all the statements. You can't use `ALTER PROC` to change the code in a procedure, it can only be used to change some of its attributes.

There's no need for a procedure with a loop, it can be done in a single query.

```
UPDATE flights 
SET price = price * 1.05
WHERE departure = 'Thailand'
```